# Composer generates differnt package directory names with same composer.json file

Tags: yii2, composer-php, bower

I'm using composer to load all my dependencies for my Yii2 application.
I also manage bower stuff with composer using Asset Packagist.

If I roll out my appication to an different system, I notice, that the same `composer.json` generates different ressouce directories.

Example:

I load the rowGrid library from Asset Packagist using the following line in the `composer.json` file:

```
"bower-asset/rowGrid.js": "1.0.6",
```

On my development machine this creates an folder like this `/path/to/vendor/stuff/bower-asset/rowGrid.js`.

Running the same composerfile on different machine, composer creates the following path for the rowGrid library: `path/to/vendor/stuff/bower-asset/rowgrid.js`. Here, there is an smal `g` in  `rowgrid.js`, which results in problems, if the application tries to access die rowGrid library.

Why does composer uses different path-names?
...and how could I handle this problem?

//Edit:

Is there a way to define a target directors for a specific bower-library?

Comment: likely one of your environments is using fxp asset plugin, [see docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#using-fxpcomposer-asset-plugin)

Comment: @csminb good hint. But: i removed the global installed fxp asset plugin, which was set at the development macheine and did an new `composer update`. unfortunately there are still different folder names. No changes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question in the case that someone have the same issue:

On system A, the bower asset rowGrid was installed a long time ago from fxp Asset Packagist. (don't know, if this is important) At this time, die downloaded library rowGrid was installed into the bower-asset Path: `vendor/bower-asset/rowGrid.js` This is also set/documented at the  `ìnstalled.json` file.

Removing the global installed "fxp Asset Packagist"-Plugin did not change anything, because the mapping, where to install rowGrid.js, was untouched in the `installed.json`. Also `composer update` did not change anything.

But: removing the package rowGrid from system a also removed the mapping at the `installed.json`. On re-installing rowGrid library again, composer fetched the same version from Asset Packagist but probably received also the new installation path, which is now lowercase: `rowgrid.js/`. The library is now installed in   `vendor/bower-asset/rowgrid.js`

The same (last step) was happens on system b: fetching the current package with the same rowGrid release number as system a, which was installed in `vendor/bower-asset/rowgrid.js` .